# JavaScript save form on page unload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onbeforeunload, onunload

I'm trying to automatically save a form when leaving a page with JavaScript by using the following code

```
$(window).unload( function() {
    $("#registration-patient-form").submit();
});
```

Yet, somehow the form does not get submitted and I'm simply redirected to the page I'm navigating to.
Any idea on how to accomplish this?

Comment: If the user wants to leave your site, he should be able to. Use localStorage to store the values everytime they are changed, and add a sync.js to every page that stores these values onload/on a button click etc...

Comment: Onbeforeunload should be used to notify the user to may submit the form/ complete sth on the page and not to run additional code

Answer (score 0):

You should do it every x seconds. Because user can close the page at unexpected time.
1) Create a function and call it every 1 second. 
2) Check the data if it is changed.
3) If data is changed, submit